# Pass list/str from batch file to python

Tags: python, batch-file

My batch file is:

```
SET TESTLIST=['text1','text2']
python test.py %TESTLIST%
```

But python does not recognize it as list.
I need Python understand the TESTLIST as ["text1","text2"]

Comment: What does `test.py`  do?

Comment: You can't pass in anything but strings to any process, including a python script. Your script itself needs to parse the passed arguments into the appropriate Python data structures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `TEST = sys.argv[1]`, let

```
TEST = sys.arv[1:]
```

---

For example with,

```
import sys
TEST = sys.argv[1:]
print(TEST)
```

running `% test.py text1 test2` yields

```
['text1', 'test2']
```